# How to group by/ pivot ag grid on flat structured data?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to show data in ag-grid like below screenshot. I have tried this using pivot table and parent-child relationship.Data for column headers should be dynamically bind from Json (example:- from screenshot year i.e.2002,2003... should come from Json) But I am stuck how I group on this. Can anyone please help?
screenshot of expected design:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWGop.png

Here is what I have tried using pivot:- https://plnkr.co/edit/qZOo8YBtMG5kB7elsaED?p=preview
and using parent child relationship:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-header-groupheader-component-ki6wwz?file=app/app.component.ts

using Pivot mode :-

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Country",
    field: "country",
    width: 120,
    rowGroup: true,
    enableRowGroup: true
  },
  {
    headerName: "Year",
    field: "year",
    width: 90,
    pivot: true,
    enablePivot: true
  },
  {
    headerName: "Gold",
    field: "gold",
    width: 100,
    aggFunc: "sum"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Silver",
    field: "silver",
    width: 100,
    aggFunc: "sum"
  },

];
```

Using Parent-Child:-

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Country",
    field: "country",
    width: 120,
    suppressMenu: true
  },     
   {
    headerName: "2002",       
    children: [          
      {
        headerName: "Gold",
        field: "gold",
        width: 90,
        sortable: false,           
      },
      {
        headerName: "Silver",
        field: "silver",
        width: 90,
        sortable: false,           
      }
      ]
  },
```

];

Comment: Do you want to row grouping or column grouping ?

Comment: I want data grouping like from screenshot and how to put that in respective cell ->e.g.  I want united states 2002 gold ,silver record to come like Y/N same for year 2003.... and countries, year and should be dynamic like if year/city increase it should increase in grid as well